# numpy equivalent of pandas.Timestamp.floor('15min')

Tags: pandas, numpy, timestamp

I try to calculate `floor` of `datetime64` type pandas series to obtain equivalent of `pandas.Timestamp.round('15min')` for '1D', '1H', '15min', '5min', '1min' intervals.

I can do it if I convert datetime64 to pandas Timestamp directly:

`pd.to_datetime(df.DATA_CZAS.to_numpy()).floor('15min')`

But how to do that without conversion to pandas (which is quite slow) ?

Remark, I can't convert datetime64[ns] to int as :

```
df.time_variable.astype(int)
>>> cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]
type(df.time_variable)
>>> pandas.core.series.Series
df.time_variable.dtypes
>>> dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Comment: pandas [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) may be useful

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, *Numpy* allows to convert between *datetime* of different
resolutions and also integers.

So you can use the following code:

```
result = (a.astype('datetime64[m]').astype(int) // 15 * 15)\
    .astype('datetime64[m]').astype('datetime64[s]')
```

Read the above code in the following sequence:

- `a.astype('datetime64[m]')` - convert to *minute* resolution (the
  number of minutes since the Unix epoch).
- `.astype(int)` - convert to *int* (the same number of minutes, but as *int*).
- `(... // 15 * 15)` - divide by *15* with rounding down and multiply
  by *15*. Just here the rounding appears.
- `.astype('datetime64[m]')` - convert back to *datetime* (*minute*
  precision).
- `.astype('datetime64[s]')` - convert to the original (*second*)
  presicion (optional).

To test the code I created the following array:

```
a = np.array(['2007-07-12 01:12:10', '2007-08-13 01:15:12',
              '2007-09-14 01:17:16', '2007-10-15 01:30:00'], dtype='datetime64')
```

The result of my rounding down is:

```
array(['2007-07-12T01:00:00', '2007-08-13T01:15:00',
       '2007-09-14T01:15:00', '2007-10-15T01:30:00'], dtype='datetime64[s]')
```